# How to expect exception in constructor with catch-exception?

Tags: java, unit-testing, catch-exception

Is it possible to expect exception in constructor with [`catch-exception`](https://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/)? Can't figure out the syntax. For methods I am writing

```
catchException(instance).method();
```

and then, for example

```
assert caughtException() instanceof IndexOutOfBoundsException;
```

What should I write for

```
new MyClass();
```

?

Comment: Do you use any library for unit testing?

Comment: It is mentionned in the tags and text. I have added the link since people seems don't know

Comment: `catch-exteption` is the library from Google, I have added the link

Comment: It's impossible using this library. It bases on creating a proxy around your instance object - thus an instance must exist.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda if you sure it is impossible, post this as an answer I will select it if no other info

Answer (score 2):

Using catch-exception library, [recommended way](https://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/) is to use the builder pattern:

```
import com.google.common.base.Supplier; // Google Guava

Supplier<MyClass> builder = new Supplier<MyClass>() {
   @Override
    public MyClass get() {
       return new MyClass();
   }
};
verifyException(builder).get();
```

If you are using JUnit 4 for unit testing, you can use [Expected Exceptions](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html):

```
public class TestClass {  

    @Test(expected = MyException.class)  
    public void createObjectTest() {  
        MyClass object = new MyClass();  
    }  
}
```

In older version of JUnit youd simply catch your exception:

```
public class TestClass {  

    @Test  
    public void createObjectTest() {  
        try {  
            MyClass obj = new MyClass();  

            fail("An exception should be thrown!");  

        } catch (MyException e) { 
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: This is correct, thanks. I will choose this answer if no answers will come about `catch-exception`

Comment: @SuzanCioc I edited an answer by adding `catch-exception` example